# Rich, Window-like Context Menu (like Interface Builder)

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, contextmenu

I need a context menu that is similar in capabilities to what Interface Builder presents when right(control)-clicking on a view, view controller etc.:

[image]

At first sight, it looks like an `NSPanel` with its style attribute set to "HUD Panel", containing some sort of outline view.

The window itself shouldn't be difficult to implement, but the usual way of presenting a context menu on right(control)-click is by overriding the method:

```
func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu?
```

...which takes an `NSMenu` as the return value; can't pass an `NSWindow` / `NSPanel` instead.

---

Perhaps I could do something like this:

```
override func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {

    // Create our popup window (HUD Panel) and present it
    // at the location of event:

    // (...actual code omitted...)

    // Prevent any actual menu from being displayed: 
    return nil 
}
```

...but it feels like a **hack**; I am tricking the system into giving away the **timing** of the right(control)-click event by *pretending to care* about presenting an actual `NSMenu` (i.e., overriding a method explicitly intended for that), but using that timing to do **something different**.

I would also need to place some logic to dismiss the window when the user clicks somewhere else (context menues have this functionality built in).

I don't think that subclassing `NSMenu` and `NSMenuItem` to obtain the above behaviour and appearance is feasible either...

**Is there a better way?** 
**Does anybody know (or is able to guess) what Interface Builder actually does?**

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comment by @Willeke, the conditions for the panel to be shown are not exactly the same as a context menu, so it most surely is not one. This means that hijacking the method above in order to display the window is not just unelegant, but wrong. The question stands as to **How to Display the Window** (i.e., detect static, non-dragging right click).

Comment: If it looks like a window and behaves like a window, then it probably is a window. It appears on right click and control click. Unlike a context menu it doesn't appear immediately on right drag or control drag. It doesn't have anything to do with menus.

Comment: @Willeke **Thank you**; I suspected as much. The question still stands as to how to trigger the window's appearance. According to the discrepancy you pointed regarding right-drag, it looks more and more like hijacking `menu(for:)` is the wrong approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to override `rightMouseDown(with:)` from your view subclass and use that to trigger showing the panel. [NSView's implementation of that method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1806802-rightmousedown) is what calls `menu(for:)` and presents the returned menu, so your custom subclass can use it to show its custom menu panel instead of calling super.

For full behavioral consistency with both standard context menus and the menus in Interface Builder, you'll also want to handle ctrl-left-clicks by overriding `mouseDown(with:)` and check for if the event's `modifierFlags` includes `.control`.